# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occured in mscaptcha.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, captcha

I am using MS Captcha but stuck with this error. Why this error comes as it may be Timeout issue but I disabled maxtimeout and mintimeout to value 0.

Would Some one describe how MS Captcha is working exactly.

Here are the aspx code and Code Behind Error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: unless you provide proper description no one will be able to help you. Provide your example code, what you have tried and where you failed. :-)

Comment: `Would Some one describe how MS Captcha is working exactly.` - sure [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) can tell you almost everything.

Comment: please add your code then it will be easy for us to help you.

Comment: I have uploaded error pics. Check Please. Whenever I posted my form it gives this error on code behind.

Comment: what is the name CaptchaControl?? i think you are using invalid captcha controll name.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too. I found that doing the following fixed it: -

```
    CaptchaControl1.ErrorInputTooFast = String.Empty
    CaptchaControl1.ErrorInputTooSlow = String.Empty
```